# Does LLVM support exception Handling for Arm Architecture

Tags: llvm, clang

Is exception Handling support provided for Arm Architecture as per now by LLVM.
I am using CLANG++ with LLVM (version 3.0) and generating Arm binaries.   But there is a problem with exception handling that whenever the code throws an exception , the code terminates with error " terminate after throwing an exception ".\

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified the platform... EH should fully be supported on arm/darwin. The stuff on arm/linux is not so good, it's work in progress there.